# Search items through ListView in C#

Tags: c#

I'm a C# programming beginner. I am programming a `ListView` which has items and subitems like Name and Address etc.
My objective now is to do a search by putting a Button after entering a word like Name in the textbox.
I am copying the code statement below. You may see that the code goes through compile successfully, but it does not work as I am trying to do.
I am trying to build a program that finds words that match words in `ListView` and focus on the words. If not find a word, then show an error message.
Is a statement, ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 correct?
Or the For Loop.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

```cs
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = Name.Text;
    if (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        return;

        var item = ListView1.SelectedItems[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {

            if (ListView1.Items[0].Text.Contains(Name.Text))
            {
                if (ListView1.FocusedItem != null)
                    ListView1.FocusedItem.Focused = false;
                    
                if (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                    ListView1.SelectedItems[0].Selected = false;

                ListView1.Items[i].Selected = true;

                ListView1.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues:

```
if (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
   return;
```

Will cause your method to never do anything. Remove the return.

```
ListView1.Items[0].Text.Contains(Name.Text)
```

you are always checking the first item in the list. It should probably be

```
ListView1.Items[i].Text.Contains(Name.Text)
```

You should probably also not show an error for each non-matching item, you should probably return once you have found the first item in your list that matches your criteria, and move the error after the loop, so it is only run if there are no matches.

Comment: `if (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count < 1) return;` is probably the guard clause that they intended to do. No items should mean no search happens